# Mercurial SSH connection fails on Linux RedHat 5

Tags: linux, mercurial, ssh, redhat, bitbucket

I am trying to set up SSH connection to Bitbucket using Mercurial.
I first generated public key, save it, ran ssh-agent, save the public key at bitbucket.
I followed all steps at link : http://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678.
I have changed hgrc file at "analysis" repository as

```
[path]
default = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/ALab/analysis
....
[ui]
username = Cassie <cassie...@...>
```

However, when I typed

```
hg push
```

It gave me error message such as

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/Cassie/.ssh/id_rsa': 
remote: Request for subsystem 'hg -R ALab/analysis serve --stdio' failed on channel 0
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

I searched online but not many posts about "fail on channel 0". Anyone has some idea ?
I tried connecting on different local repositories but they all got the same error problem.

Updated part :

I am sorry that I just solved this problem and didn't know how to delete this post.
So if someone can be kind to let me know, I would like to delete this post by myself.

To help other who encountered similar problem, I forgot to add "ssh = ssh -C" on the configure
file which is required. Thank you very much,

Comment: Thanks for adding the solution. You can actually add this as an answer to your own question, and then later an (2 days, I think) accept it. That way, it helps other people, and also it shows up as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Clare thanks for your idea. Thus, let me answer the question again.
I found out that I have to put `ssh = ssh -C` for all the hgrc files of my local
repositories to make push via SSH successfully. Hope it helps.